# How to set PHP-Processing screen color to black (don't want white screen)

Tags: php

On the site I have developed, the user must login with a $_POST request to validate credentials. I have implemented a jQuery UI effect that makes the screen black (and does some animation on the black screen) before the login form undergoes a submit() event. 
When the submit() is $_POSTed, the credentials are validated and header() is used to redirect to 'home.php'. This animation is then "continued" (black color plus animation) as home.php loads, and finally the page "appears" after the body has loaded.

The problem is this: in the brief moment that includes the login validation on login.php and the PHP processing in home.php, there is a white flash that I DO NOT want.

**Here is the sequence I want:**
    click login button (not black screen) ---> jQuery animation (black screen) ----> form submit (still black screen) ----> $_POST validation (still black screen) ---> header('location: home.php') (still black screen)----> PHP processing (still black screen) ----> jQuery animation (still black screen) ----> page is revealed (not black screen)

**Here is the sequence I get:**
    click login button (not black screen) ---> jQuery animation (black screen) ----> form submit (still black screen) ----> $_POST validation (now a white screen) ---> header('location: home.php') (white screen)----> PHP processing (white screen) ----> jQuery animation (now a black screen) ----> page is revealed (not black screen)

To reiterate, during PHP processing, the page flashes white, briefly but noticeably, between black screens.

The file home.php has a massive, intricate block of PHP before the `<html>` tag, and needs to be kept as is. I am looking for a function that does what I need. I googled "PHP set screen color" and related searches, but I only get hits regarding image colors.

Is there any PHP function that would set the default screen color to black during this flash (PHP processing phase) so that instead of a brief white flash, it is a brief black flash?

Comment: Is the login form in the same page of the script which processes the data? I mean, everything is done by home.php?

Comment: No...the login is done on a landing page (not home.php), and after $_POST processing and validation, a successful login is redirected via header() to home.php

Comment: And it is this when the script calls this landing page that you see the white screen, right? EDIT: Oh, yes, it's login.php. Have you tried to set the background color to black just in the body of that page?

Comment: The login is validated in PHP and PHP also processes lots of data to load home.php, so there is a continuous block of time from login.php validation to home.php preprocessing where the screen is white

Comment: Because this period of time is less than a second, it shows up as a white flash